# How can I figure out how long the account holds the NFT?

Tags: contract-development, nft

I'm reading this article: https://research.checkpoint.com/2022/airdrop-process-of-apecoin-cryptocurrency-found-vulnerable-led-to-theft-of-millions-of-dollars-in-nfts/

And quote:

> The main bug was that the ApeCoin airdrop didn’t check how long the holder had the Bored Ape NFT. Instead, it was claimable by anyone who owns a Bored Ape at the point of claiming the airdrop.

So in the contract how can I figure out how long the holder had the NFT? What is the best practise?